# Regular expression to match A, AB, ABC, but not AC. ("starts with")

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm banging my head against a wall. I want a regex that matches: empty string, `A`, `AB`, and `ABC`, but not `AC`. I have this, which works:

```
/^(A|AB|ABC)?$/
```

But this is a simplification; in my app `A`, `B`, and `C` are actually long character classes, so I don't want to repeat them over and over. Maybe I'm just not looking at it the right way. I tried this:

```
/^((AB?)C?)?$/
```

But that still matches `AC`.

Is there a simpler way to do this, that could be extended to (say), `ABCD`, `ABCDE`, etc.?

**Edit**: By extend to `ABCDE`, I mean it would match: empty string, `A`, `AB`, `ABC`, `ABCD`, `ABCDE`. Basically, a "starts with" regex.

Comment: In what way do you want to extend it?

Comment: `C` cannot be preceed by an `A`, or `A` must be followed by a `B`?

Comment: So you want to allow `ABCD` but not `ACD` and `ABCDE` but not `ACDE`?

Comment: Sorry, I clarified how I meant for it to be extended. It is kind of a "starts with" regex that I guess I'm really looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^(A(B(C)?)?)?$
```

I think you can see the pattern and expand it for `ABCD` and `ABCDE` like:

```
^(A(B(C(D)?)?)?)?$
^(A(B(C(D(E)?)?)?)?)?$
```

Now each part depends on the preceeding parts (*B* depends on *A*, *C* depends on *B*, etc.).

Comment: thanks. i can't believe i didn't think to just change the grouping. and this is easy to extend: `^(A(B(C(D(E)?)?)?)?)?$`. This site is super fast too, I went to grab a coffee after posting and there were already three correct answers when i got back

Comment: @CarlSmotricz actually it works flawlessly when C is not a single character.

Answer (score 7):

```
/^A(?:B(?:C)?)?$/
```

should do it.

This is using the non-capturing group construct `(?: xxx )` so as not to mess up any match capturing you may be doing.

Comment: thanks. to match empty string you'd have to match the whole thing in another `(?: ... )?`

Comment: @Jenni: yep, another level of nesting should do it.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
/^A(BC?)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little extravagant, but it works for character classes as well as characters.

(You would always use indexOf if it could be expressed as a string.)

You used to be able to edit a RegExp, but now you need a new one with any change.

```
RegExp.prototype.extend= function(c){
 var s= '', rx= this.toString();
 rx= rx.replace(/(\W+)$/, c+'$1').replace(/^\/|\/$/g,'');
 if(this.global) s+= 'g';
 if(this.multiline) s+= 'm';
 if(this.ignoreCase) s+= 'i';
 return RegExp(rx, s);
}

String.prototype.longMatch= function(arr){
 // if(this=='') return true;
 var Rx= RegExp("^("+arr.shift()+")");
 var i= 0, L= Math.min(s.length, arr.length),
 M= this.match(Rx);
 while(i< L){
  if(!M) return false;
  Rx= Rx.extend(arr[i++]);
  M= this.match(Rx);
 }
 return M[0]==this;
}

var arr= ['A','B','C','D'];
var s= 'ABCD';// try various strings
alert(s.longMatch(arr));
```