# regex – matching suffix same as given word

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python3 with `re` module. I would like to remove `address:` from a start of a string, but I would also like to remove all of `address` suffixes in the beginning of a string:

```py
'address: foobar' -> 'foobar'
'ddress: foobar' -> 'foobar'
'dress: foobar' -> 'foobar'
'ress: foobar' -> 'foobar'
'ess: foobar' -> 'foobar'
'ss: foobar' -> 'foobar'
's: foobar' -> 'foobar'
```

I came up with this matching regex pattern:

```py
r'^(?:address|ddress|dress|ress|ess|ss|s)?[ :]+'
```

But I'm wondering, is there a simpler (correct) way to do this with regex without manually repeating all suffixes?

Comment: You could shorten it a bit to `^(?:address|dd?ress|ress|ess|ss?)?[ :]+`

Comment: Yes, that way, or the way described in the linked post. There is no magic regex construct to build these variations for you.

Comment: reverse string then do cascading delete, reverse string again. how ? yes esay

Comment: each different but plug into stringlator it `^(?:address|dd?ress|r?ess|ss?):`

Comment: how dup anwser questin ? no ?

Comment: You can use [^((((((a)?d)?d)?r)?e)?s)?s](https://regex101.com/r/EwF9nK/1/)

Comment: @Federico's regex is decidedly better than Thefourthbird's, for [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), as it's 11 characters shorter.

Comment: @CarySwoveland both Federico's and Edward's patterns are better than mine. Was this not marked as a dupe?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I missed Edward's, but it's waaay too long for Code Golf.

Comment: One more: replace matches of `r'(?<=^')(?:a(?=d))?(?:d(?=d))?(?:d(?=r))?(?:r(?=e))?(?:e(?=s))?(?:s(?=s))?s:\s'` with empty strings. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3LLL8P/1/)

Comment: oh for cornersuars this fastest [^(?:address|dd?ress|r?ess|ss?)](https://regex101.com/r/BPUl7p/1) with 79 steps,  this shortest char len for golferiers
[^(((a?dd?)?r?e)?ss?)](https://regex101.com/r/GPRWha/1)  and 101 steps

Comment: if notice this is last to first. that list duplercut is first to last. haha just the opasite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex looks ok to me, but I come up with an alternative for fun.

You can use:

```
^((((((a)?d)?d)?r)?e)?s)?s
```

I'm using capturing groups for readability, but you can use non capturing groups.

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:a)?d)?d)?r)?e)?s)?s
```

[image]

[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/EwF9nK/1/)

Comment: I closed the question because it has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132262) many [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007277) already. I even deleted [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396693) with 9 upvotes because it was a dupe and people discussed it on meta, and closed the question, and deleted it later. Please do not reopen duplicate questions that are known duplicates.

Comment: i like yurs it can be programitic. with help it can be shorter too [^(((a?dd?)?r?e)?ss?)](https://regex101.com/r/GPRWha/1)